# mysql trigger update not working

Tags: mysql, database-trigger

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER arrange_serial
 AFTER DELETE ON db.table
 FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
   UPDATE db.table set serial=serial-1 where serial > DELETED.serial;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

On delete I'm getting the error that `db.DELETED` does not exist. Can anyone suggest me where I'm wrong.

Comment: You seem to have a mash up of sqlserver and mysql(or oracle) code) here and in mysql you cannot action the table in a trigger which caused the trigger to fire.

Answer (score 0):

You are supposed to reference the old value of the deleted row. Use `OLD` in the place of `DELETED`;

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER arrange_serial
 AFTER DELETE ON db.table
 FOR EACH ROW 
 BEGIN
   UPDATE db.table set serial=serial-1 where serial > OLD.serial;
 END$$
DELIMITER ;
```